# How to display nested queries in React GraphQL?

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I'm working in React, trying to turn my nested GraphQL query into a list.

So far, in GraphiQL the following query is producing the order and general structure of what I'm looking for. Basically, for each `tag` I want the `fieldValue` displayed, and then under each `tag` I want to list the `node.fields.slug` for each item that has that `tag`.

```
query MyQuery {
  allMarkdownRemark {
    group(field: frontmatter___tags) {
      tag: fieldValue
      totalCount
      edges {
        node {
          fields {
            slug
          }
          frontmatter {
            title
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So far the only part I've gotten to work correctly is listing each `tag`  :

```
{data.articles.group.map(({ tag }) => (
    <ul>
        <li>{ tag }</li>
    </ul>
))}
```

How would I go about getting each tag's items listed underneath the respective tag name?

Comment: put the data that react should displayed. you will get help about people using react and not graphql. 
the map should be inside <ul> like this `<ul>{data.articles.group.map(({ tag }) => (
        <li>{ tag }</li>
))} </ul>` other wise your are creating many `<ul><li/></ul>` but you want `<ul><li/><li/><li/><li/></ul>`

Comment: you can put a map inside another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually figured it out. I ended up writing

```
{data.articles.group.map(({ tag, edges }) => (
    <ul>
        <h3>{ tag }</h3>
        { edges.map(({ node }) => (
            <li>{node.frontmatter.title}</li>
        ))}
    </ul>
))}
```